# buffer's socket to queue issue

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, queue

I have some  code:

a declaration of a queue:

```
typedef deque<char*, allocator<char*> > CHARDEQUE;
typedef queue<char*,CHARDEQUE> CHARQUEUE;

CHARQUEUE p;
size_t size_q;
char recv_data[1024];
```

I use a udp socket to receive data from a distant machine:

this is the loop:

```
while (1)
{
  bytes_read = recvfrom(sock,recv_data,1024,0, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &addr_len);

  p.push(recv_data);
  size_q=p.size();
  printf("%d\n",size_q);
}
```

but the problem is that I can't copy data to my queue which is what i want, I could just point to it...can any one help in this?

for more information, my program is receiving raw data, that's why i use char array..
any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are pushing a "char*" which is a pointer into your queue, not the actual data!

Use a `std::vector<char>`, as below (no error checking etc - which you should do btw.!):

```
std::deque<std::vector<char> > p;


std::vector<char> read_buff;

// per loop iteration
read_buff.resize(1024);
// read
bytes_read = recvfrom(sock,&read_buff[0], 1024,0, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &addr_len);
// now resize to contents
read_buff.resize(bytes_read);

// push this
p.push_back(read_buff);
```

Comment: In this case it's probably worth doing the check to avoid pushing empty vectors onto the queue.

Comment: Can we use queue instead of dequeue...and could u tell me the difrence  between them?

Comment: a `std::queue` is a wrapper around another type of container, and by default this is a `std::deque`. If I had a choice, I would use `std::deque` directly - but that's my preference I guess...

Comment: ok, plausible enough, let's say we want to print what in the read_buffer to screen assuming that I receive 4 character {'h','e','l','o'},can we do sth like this: printf("%s",q.front());
 q.pop_front(); thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't use `printf`, however you can use `std::cout` and `std::ostream_iterator`, for example: `std::copy(q.front().begin(), q.front().end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, "")); q.pop_front();`

Comment: just another question...how to copy the data from the queue to the socket..should I use another write_buff vector, copy the vector from the queue to the write_buff and then point in the sendto buffer to the first element of write_buff?or there is another solution more simple?..

Comment: No you don't need to do that, you should just be able to use the vector in the queue directly, and only pop the front once the `send` has completed.